# Regular expression match group

Tags: python, regex

I know this is a very simple regex problem, but I still get stuck in matching it.

The string needed to be match is `"10K-50K"`

I want to extract the 10 and 50 from the string using regular expression.

```
In [6]: data = "10K-50K"

In [7]: data1 = re.match(r'([\d][A-Z])-([\d][A-Z])',data)
```

However, it always returned a `Nonetype`.

I am confused with regex syntax and hope someone could help me.

Comment: You're matching a single digit, followed by a single capital letter. But your string is two digits, followed by a single capital letter. You probably want to match one or more digits, so you need a `+`. See [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CpS78K/1). If you want exactly two digits, or two to four but no more or less, etc., of course you'll have to adjust it appropriately.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need a `[]` class for a single character or builtin class, so you can just do `\d+[A-Z]` instead of `[\d]+[A-Z]`, and it's probably a bit more readable without the extra brackets.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the numbers you want to extract. Are they always two-digits long? Are they always followed by a `K`? Is this `xxK-xxK` format permanent?

Comment: Thank you all,guys.  I am matching (one or more digits)K- (one or more)K string. According to your explanation, it should be written in something like re.match(r'(\d+)[A-Z]-(\d+)[A-Z]',data).groups() and it worked. It is my first time on stackoverflow, thank you all again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import re

data = "10K-50K"
str_tokens = re.match(r'([0-9]*)[a-zA-Z]-([0-9]*)[a-zA-Z]', data).groups()
int_tokens = [int(token) for token in str_tokens]

print(str_tokens, int_tokens)
```

Output:

```
('10', '50') [10, 50]
```